# Why this.$ is not available in Ember Controller

Tags: ember.js

`Ember.$` is available in the controller whereas `this.$` is not. But it is available in components.

`Ember.$(".loading-splash").hide();` is working on controller where as
`this.$(".loading-splash").hide();` is throwing an exception `"this.$() is unavailable"`

Comment: what ember-source version is this?

Answer (score 4):

Ember components have a `this.element`, a place in the DOM to which they are attached. Older versions of Ember, 3.x and below, wrap this element with a `this.$()` so that you can conveniently use JQuery with that element as a context.

For example, this.$('.some-class') will locate elements with some-class within the scope of the component, i.e. within the component's element. Ember.$('.some-class') will locate elements with some-class anywhere in the page.

JQuery integration was made an optional feature in Ember 3.4, was no longer enabled by default in 3.14, and finally deprecated late in 3.x cycle and removed in Ember 4.0.

Controllers and Glimmer components are not associated with an element in the DOM, so there is not `this.element` to wrap.